# Moodle Database - Reverse Engineering ERD

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, moodle, erd, dbeaver

I want to create an ERD for my moodle database.
Which tools do you recommend?
How can I force Moodle to create the foreign keys?

Thanks in advance

I tried DBeaver.
There are no relations displayed between the tables.
Moodle does not create any foreign keys by default.

Comment: Ask Moodle. But it looks like it doesn't create any foreign keys: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=432286

Answer (score 0):

There are semi-official schema diagrams available from [Moodle's developer documentation](https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/core/dml/database-schema), although I personally don't care for the viewer for the chosen file format (DBDesigner4).

If you want to create your own ERD, [MDL-49795](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-49795?focusedId=923420&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-923420) has some tips, namely:

> Standard Moodle will not even install let alone work if the PK/FK relationships are actually implemented. I regularly (yearly?) do create a Moodle database from a custom SQL script that has the PK/FK relationships enabled by adding this to the start of the DDL sql for MySQL to
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
>
> That enables the database creation but it would break if you try to actually run Moodle with it.